# Can I call a function in angular [routerLink] to set the query parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript

The api gives a response without ID. Like this:

```
export interface Character {
    url: string;
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    culture: string;
    born: string;
    died: string;
    titles: string[];
    aliases: string[];
    father: string;
    mother: string;
    spouse: string;
    allegiances: string[];
    books: string[];
    povBooks: string[];
    tvSeries: string[];
    playedBy: string[];
}
```

But I would like to make a route to my `/characters/:id`, but since I don't have an ID in this response, I should take it out of the `url` sent by the API since it looks like this: `https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/38`

My plan is to get the id out of the url. Something like this:

```
<p>Characters:
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let character of characters | async">
       <a  [routerLink]="['/characters', getCharacterId()]">{{character.name}}</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

So at the `[routerLink]="['/characters', getCharacterId()]` part, I should extract the id out of the URL somehow, but I got no idea how is it possible? Can I call a function like that?

The function would be:

```
getCharacterId(character: Character) {
        return character.url.substr(character.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use **getter** or u can use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="getCharacterId(character) as characterId">
<a [routerLink]="['/characters', characterId]">{{character.name}}</a>
</ng-container>
```

but better make class from interface, in class constructor make your ID and where u get characters (service) do something like this:

```
return http.get<Character[]>('http://some_url').pipe(map(res => (res||[]).map(c => new Character(c))));
```

so from now u have array of mapped classes who can already have characterID

Comment: The <a> tags are not shown if I use your first code. I think the *ngIf becomes false every time... Also I tried to make a `CharacterWithId` interface what is similar to `Character` but I added an `id: string` field. I added `charactersWithId: Observable<CharacterWithId[]> | undefined;` to component but I don't know how to convert the `characters: Observable<Character[]> | undefined;` to that... Always getting some errors.

Comment: create some stackblitz sample and i will help you with error

Answer (score 0):

You can call funcation on click of a tag

```
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="redirect(character)">{{character.name}}</a>
```

Define function in component and navigate to path with queryParams

```
redirect(character){
   const id = character.url.substr(character.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
   this.router.navigate(['/characters'],{ queryParams: { characterId: id}});   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 <p>Characters:</p>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let character of characters | async">
       <a [routerLink]="['/characters', character.url.split('/').reverse()[0]]">{{character.name}}</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

I am using below code to split your URL with '/' and pick out the last one (basically reversing it and picking 1st one here) You could change this logic as per your requirement:

```
character.url.split('/').reverse()[0]
```